# png images with transparency disappear in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, png, mod-pagespeed, png-24

[link](http://floridaseating.com/products/classic-indoor-collection)

at first, the png images will load, then disappear in IE9.

not quite sure.

thanks.

UPDATE. i have mod_pagespeed enabled, which seems to be related to the issue. i disabled the plugin, and the issue was resolved. any way to have it enabled, and have images display as they should?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a mod_pagespeed bug. Please submit a bug-report here: https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/list

But a temporary work-around is to use [ModPagespeedDisallow](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/restricting_urls) for these images.